# API Application single port multiple app IIS

Tags: .net, iis, .net-core

I have around 5 API projects in one Solution which built by .NET Core Visual Studio 2019.
I want to publish to IIS Manager with single port. Let say, Project1 - 8081, Project2 - 8081, ff.

Currently, each projects have a different port.
So Front-End access with some url like, `https://<ipadd:portno>/Project1/API_Action`

How can I do that? Because when I tried with same port. It shows me a warning say that duplicate binding.

Thank you.

Comment: If you want to bind to the same port, then they should have different IP addresses or host names, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html#background

Comment: Hi, tq. How can I set it up in IIS? To be honest, I am newbie in IIS. I just edit the question.

Comment: After your edits, I don't think you should host those 5 projects at the same port. Instead, keep the current setup, but add a reverse proxy. The reverse proxy can serve `https://some-ip/` at port 443 and delegate calls on `https://some-ip/project1` to port 8081, and so on. That's the common API gateway pattern.

Comment: Yes, that is the current setting @LexLi . Is it possible to change it to single port with multiple app?

Comment: Hi, has the problem been solved? If you think my reply is helpful to you, you can mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, a port number can only be used by one application. If you want to share a port number with more applications, I think you can add sub-applications under the main application:

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE:**

[image]

The URL of the sub application is the URL of the main application + Alias.

Comment: So how can Front-End access the sub-application? Can you give an example?